# create boxplots of quantiles against binary endpoint

Tags: r, boxplot, quantile

I am trying to plot boxplots of quantiles of the numeric continuos variables (x-axis) with the binary end points(y-axis) .

my inuput data is:

```
ID  endpoint    var2    var3    var4    var5
1   0   62  3.1 13  10.1
2   1   150 4.1 9   11.1
3   0   18  5.1 0.6 12.1
4   0   60  6.1 3   13.1
5   0   20  7.1 1   14.1
6   1   100 8.1 19  15.1
7   0   56  9.1 2   16.1
8   1   36  10.1    5   17.1
9   0   33.2    11.1    4   18.1
10  1   200 12.1    64  19.1
```

Please help to do this plotting in R.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you examined the help functions for `boxplot` (__`?boxplot()`__) and `quantile` (__`?quantile()`__)?

Comment: @bouncyball, I have tried numcolwise.

Comment: @bouncyball, I have tried numcolwise. numcolwise(quantile)(mydata, na.rm = T) this function calculates the quntiles but struggling to put the values in a plot (quantiles on x-axis) and endpoint on Y-axis for all the variables. endpoint var3 var4 var5 0 8 0.68 0.3 0 80 1.365 8 0 100 1.89 31 0.5 100 2.755 54 1 300 9.02 78

Comment: Do you want a box for each continuous variable (var2 - var5) for each endpoint?

Comment: @bouncyball, yes, for each continuous varable

Comment: Someone can help to make these plots.? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try `melt {reshape2}` and then plot with either `base` R or `ggplot` as follows:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

data = read.table(text="ID  endpoint    var2    var3    var4    var5
1   0   62  3.1 13  10.1
           2   1   150 4.1 9   11.1
           3   0   18  5.1 0.6 12.1
           4   0   60  6.1 3   13.1
           5   0   20  7.1 1   14.1
           6   1   100 8.1 19  15.1
           7   0   56  9.1 2   16.1
           8   1   36  10.1    5   17.1
           9   0   33.2    11.1    4   18.1
           10  1   200 12.1    64  19.1",header=TRUE)
head(data)

# Melt data
data.melt = melt(data[,2:6],id='endpoint')
head(data.melt)

# Boxplot with base
boxplot(value~endpoint*variable, data=data.melt, col=(c("red","green",'blue'))) 

# Boxplot with ggplot
ggplot(data.melt, aes(x=as.factor(endpoint), y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Hope it helps.